# How to calculate means based on content in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am not very familiar with R and I have `df` that looks like this:

```
df = data.frame(pathway=c("A","A","A","B","B"), S1=c(10,20,25, 15, 20), S2=c(2,4,5,7,8))
rownames(df) = c("G1","G2","G3","G4","G5")

df
   pathway S1 S2
G1       A 10  2
G2       A 20  4
G3       A 25  5
G4       B 15  7
G5       B 20  8
```

Instead of having only `S1` and `S2`, there are 130, so up to `S130`. Also, there are 20 different `pathways`, like from `A` to `U`.

I would like to calculate the mean of the value in `pathway A` and `pathway B`, etc for `S1`, `S2` and so on. The desire output is like:

```
 pathway   S1    S2
       A 18.3  3.67
       B 17.5   7.5
```

I could not figure out how to do this. Could someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be made easily using the aggregate function

```
 aggregate(cbind(df$S1, df$S2), #Columns to aggregate
      by = list(category = df$pathway), FUN = mean) # by category and function to apply

# Output:
   A 18.33333 3.666667
   B 17.50000 7.500000
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Is there any way to simplify the `df$S1, df$S2` part, since I have 130 columns from `S1` to `S130`?

Comment: @kin182, try `aggregate(.~pathway, df, mean)`

Comment: @d.b. Thanks so much! This one rocks!

Answer (score 2):

I would try the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -pathway) %>% 
  group_by(pathway, key) %>% 
  summarise(group_mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  pathway   key group_mean
   <fctr> <chr>      <dbl>
1       A    S1  18.333333
2       A    S2   3.666667
3       B    S1  17.500000
4       B    S2   7.500000
```

This way, you will be able to compute the mean of `S1`, `S2`, ... , `S130`, etc. After which, you can reformat the table to what your desired output looks like by adding `spread(key, group_mean)` at the end of the chain:

```
df %>% 
  gather(key, value, -pathway) %>% 
  group_by(pathway, key) %>% 
  summarise(group_mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  spread(key, group_mean)

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   pathway [2]
  pathway       S1       S2
*  <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1       A 18.33333 3.666667
2       B 17.50000 7.500000
```